Wifi dropping - it used to be OK
I must post this from an old Win PC. My wifi on my Ubuntu keeps failing but the Win wifi is good. The PCs are adjacent.
For years the Ubuntu wifi worked, then about 3 months ago problems started. The wifi dies after about 10 to 20 mins. I have to stop the wifi and restart it. Then it is good for the next 10-20 mins.
I suspected the wifi dongle (it is an old one, quite slow) so I tried another old one but the problem remained.
(I cannot use the Win wifi dongle. It does not work on Linux)
I have looked at the 'Wifi dropping' posts but the most recent one is from 2017 and does not help.
I have the latest Ubuntu LTS installed
I have never loaded a driver myself. I have just used the one that comes with Ubuntu. And it used to work.
What next? Do I have a corrupted driver? An out of date driver?

Thanks. There I found this helpful post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnose...
Then I did as instructed:
Post the results on paste.ubuntu.com ..., and link to it here in your question.
Here it is:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DB7ShJ5mmr/

You have 2 drivers trying to control the wifi, rtl8192cu and rtl8xxxu  you may have to blacklist one and see if it is better after reboot

Thanks Jeremy - My wifi dongle uses the rtl8192cu driver.
I followed these steps
To blacklist the rtl8xxxu driver, you can follow these steps:


Edit the blacklist file:
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf


Add the following line to the file:
blacklist rtl8xxxu


Save the file and reboot your system.
After rebooting, the rtl8xxxu driver should be disabled, and your system should use the rtl8192cu driver.


But it did not work. Wifi starts then quickly drops again.
Help !

Remove rtl8xxxu from blacklist, add the rtl8192cu to blacklist and reboot

Jeremy's advice to blacklist the 'wrong' driver has worked.
As said in my initial post when the problem unexpectedly occurred without any obvious cause, I tried with a 2nd USB wifi dongle and the problem remained unchanged.
Then I got the advice from him to blacklist the 2nd driver, which I tried but it did not work. But then I kept the drivers (one now blacklisted) and swapped back to the first wifi dongle.
Strangely, this should have taken me back to my earlier problem, but it is OK now. How did I get 2 drivers? A question for another day.
